# Wordpress Post Editor File

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have no knowledge in PHP and am reading up on it as of now. However, in the meantime I'm trying to make changes to the Wordpress posts editor HTML and CSS code, but I cannot find the correct file for this.

Does anyone have any clue on where I can find documentation or the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation you're after: [WordPress Dashboard API](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/dashboard-widgets/)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommended first check the hierarchy of wordpress.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/